# Why do I get a number in brackets on my web site project name?

Tags: asp.net, web, visual-studio-2013

This is just a curiosity/annoyance and not really an issue.

I have a web forms web site project using VS 2013. Somehow, the project name includes a **(1)** or a **(2)** in the name, I have tried editing the solution file, deleting all other sites, rebuilding/cleaning etc, still cannot figure out where it gets the **(2)** from.

[image]

**Solution File :**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.30501.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "Site", "http://localhost:52806", "{5411FD57-5AFE-4A3A-9474-0DCD64C89003}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_52806"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\Dropbox\Projects\Site\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_52806\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_52806"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\Dropbox\Projects\Site\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_52806\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\Dropbox\Projects\Site\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {5411FD57-5AFE-4A3A-9474-0DCD64C89003}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5411FD57-5AFE-4A3A-9474-0DCD64C89003}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might have two sites with the same IIS binding information. This usually happens to me if I create, delete, then re-create a web site.

Find your IISExpress folder (mine is in C:\Users\brandon\Documents\IISExpress), then go to config/applicationhost.config

Find your site name with the duplicate binding and remove the `<site>` node. It will look something like this

```
<site name="WEBSITENAME" id="21">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\...\YourProject" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:SomePortNumber:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Comment: Perfect! Finally I know why.

Comment: If you don't find the binding in that file, try the `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` file as mentioned in Frederik Struck-Schøning's answer

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I simply deleted the `.vs` folder in my solution root. It contained `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` and `.vs\mySolutionName\v14\.suo`.

Editing one of those files, possibly deleting the old IIS Express binding or something, might be the pretty way of doing it. But whacking the .vs-folder and reloading solution did the trick for me.

Comment: I found the binding in the `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` file and deleted it from there.  All looking good now thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check `My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` with notepad or similar; there should be one or more entries with `site (x)`.

[edit]
Brandon [beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24048869/215042) by 18 seconds...